# Método não inicia na primeira vez (Constructor ou IonViewDidEnter)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Tenho uma função que deveria ser carregada e gerar uma lista no momento que a page é carregada, mas não acontece como deveria. Ao clicar na aba referente à tela, não é carregada a função - indo para outra view e clicando novamente, aí é carregado normalmente. A função no caso é a loadHistorico(), está sendo chamada no IonViewDidEnter(), já coloquei no construtor e o resultado foi o mesmo.

```
import { HistoricoModel } from './../../models/HistoricoModel';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertController, LoadingController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CaixaModel } from './../../models/CaixaModel';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PaginaBase } from '../../infra/PaginaBase';
import { ICaixaService } from './../../providers-interfaces/ICaixaService';
import { CaixasimpleProvider } from './../../providers/caixasimple/caixasimple';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { CredenciadoProvider } from '../../providers/credenciado/credenciado';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-credenciado-caixa',
  templateUrl: 'credenciado-caixa.html',
  providers: [
    CaixasimpleProvider,
    CredenciadoProvider,
  ]
})
export class CredenciadoCaixaPage extends PaginaBase {
  foiSubmetido: boolean;
  caixaModel: CaixaModel;
  public currentCred;
  public loader;
  public io = new Array<any>();
  public total = "";
  historicoModel: HistoricoModel[];
  public isEmpty: boolean = false;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    @Inject('ICaixaService')
    public caixaservice: ICaixaService,
    private nativeStorage: NativeStorage,
    public http: HttpClient,
    public CaixasimpleProvider: CaixasimpleProvider,
    public CredenciadoProvider: CredenciadoProvider) {
    super({
      formBuilder: formBuilder,
      alertCtrl: alertCtrl,
      loadingCtrl: loadingCtrl,
      toastCtrl: toastCtrl
    })
    this.foiSubmetido = false;
    this.caixaModel = new CaixaModel();
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('idCredenciado')
      .then(
        dados => this.currentCred = (dados.idCredenciado), error => { console.log(error); })
    console.log(this.currentCred);
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.loadHistorico();
    this.setIsEmpty();
  }

  setIsEmpty() {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('idCredenciado').then(
      dados => this.CaixasimpleProvider.getHistoricoForIsEmpty(dados.idCredenciado).subscribe(
        data => {
          const response = (data as any);
          if(response == ""){
            this.isEmpty = true;
          }else{
            this.isEmpty = false;
          }
        }
      ));
  }

  loadHistorico() {
    this.showLoading();
    console.log("currentcred no ionviewdidenter -> " + this.currentCred);
    this.CaixasimpleProvider.getTotalFluxoCaixa(this.currentCred).subscribe(
      data => {
        var retorno = (data as any);
        this.total = retorno[0].soma;
      }, error => {
        this.closeLoading();
        console.log(error);
      });

    this.CaixasimpleProvider.getImputOutput(this.currentCred).subscribe(
      data => {
        const response = (data as any);
        console.log(response);
        this.io = response;
        console.log(this.io);
      }, error => {
        this.closeLoading();
        console.log(error);
      });

    this.CaixasimpleProvider.getHistorico(this.currentCred)
      .subscribe(data => {
        var retorno = (data as any);
        this.historicoModel = retorno;
      }, error => {
        this.closeLoading();
        console.log(error);
      });
    this.closeLoading();
  }

  cadastrarValor(caixaModel: CaixaModel): void {
    this.foiSubmetido = true;
    this.esconderToast();
    const mensagem = "Entrada de valor cadastrada!";
    const mensagemErro = "Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente, não iremos decepcionar :)";

    this.CaixasimpleProvider.cadastrarValor(this.caixaModel)
      .subscribe(dados => {
        this.mostrarToast(mensagem);
      },
        erro => { this.mostrarToast(mensagemErro); });
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
  }

  cadastrarValorNeg(caixaModel: CaixaModel): void {
    this.foiSubmetido = true;
    this.esconderToast();
    const mensagem = "Entrada de valor cadastrada!";
    const mensagemErro = "Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente, não iremos decepcionar :)";
    this.caixaModel.valor = "-".concat(this.caixaModel.valor);
    this.CaixasimpleProvider.cadastrarValor(this.caixaModel)
      .subscribe(dados => {
        this.mostrarToast(mensagem);
      },
        erro => { this.mostrarToast(mensagemErro); });
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Carregando ..."
    });
    this.loader.present();
  }
  closeLoading() {
    this.loader.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: Alexandre, o `showLoading` e  `closeLoading` é chamando em sequência assim que você abre essa tela? Tenta verificar isso com o console.log.

Comment: Olha, não percebi isso, mas acredito que também não rode, o comportamento esperado só funciona da segunda vez que entra na tela mesmo. Vou ver se o Loading aparece normal

Comment: @AndréLins funciona normalmente o showLoading e closeLoading, só a lista que deveria aparecer loadHistorico não vai

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta pra isso, acredito que ela resolve o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como todas as chamadas são assíncronas o `showLoading`e o `closeLoading` é chamado em sequência e por isso dá a impressão que não está funcionando, você pode colocar um contador e fazer o `closeLoading` só quando tiver carregado as três requisições, segue abaixo os ajustes em `loadHistorico` e `closeLoading` que resolve esse problema:

```js
  loadHistorico() {
    let count = 0; 
    this.showLoading();
    console.log("currentcred no ionviewdidenter -> " + this.currentCred);
    this.CaixasimpleProvider.getTotalFluxoCaixa(this.currentCred).subscribe(
      data => {
        count++;
        this.closeLoading(count);
        var retorno = (data as any);
        this.total = retorno[0].soma;
      }, error => {
        count++;
        this.closeLoading(count);
        console.log(error);
      });

    this.CaixasimpleProvider.getImputOutput(this.currentCred).subscribe(
      data => {
        count++;
        this.closeLoading(count);
        const response = (data as any);
        console.log(response);
        this.io = response;
        console.log(this.io);
      }, error => {
        count++;
        this.closeLoading(count);
        console.log(error);
      });

    this.CaixasimpleProvider.getHistorico(this.currentCred)
      .subscribe(data => {
        count++;
        this.closeLoading(count);
        var retorno = (data as any);
        this.historicoModel = retorno;
      }, error => {
        count++;
        this.closeLoading(count);
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  closeLoading(count) {
    if(count===3) this.loader.dismiss();
  }
```